# How to enable inline edit?

Tags: administration, inlineeditsupport

How can I enable inline-edit in my salesforce org, it is not working now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Needs no enabling. Please check if the records have record types. If it does please filter the list accordingly. I hope it works.

Comment: To clarify above:  A list view MUST include a record type in the filter in order to allow for inline editing.

Answer (score 5):

There is an option which is enabled by default in the setup.

Clickpath: Setup > Customize > User Interface

there the 6th checkbox:

[image]